# Contact names are gone, but still shown in Messages

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

My iPhone 6's contact names are gone, but the numbers are still there.

*However* when I go to messaging and add a new message and type for a contact by name, all the contacts show up with **both** the name and the message. Therefore I know that the iPhone still has the names stored somewhere, because it shows up when searching in the messaging search.

What can I do to get all my contact names back, because I know that they **are** stored somewhere.

I don't have any backups, but I shouldn't need any, because my device seems to have the contact names *somewhere*, as I see them when I add a message and search.

Comment: No backups, in this day & age? What happens if the phone gets lost, stolen or broken?

Answer (score 2):

Try these possible fixes :

1. Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > iCloud > toggle Contacts on and off

The Second fix only applies if you have multiple email accounts synced with your iPhone (iCloud,Gmail etc) :

2. Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Gmail or whichever you use > toggle Contacts on and off

Also check the Default Account in Settings to see which email account is selected.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me. I had deleted my gmail account because it was taking up too much space. I remembered the changes I made before the contact names deleted. I restored the account and my contact names were restored. Then I imported the contacts to sim from gmail and cloud so they would save.